# Tracking Leaky Memory from a Windows WCF Service using MEF & 3rd party components

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0, memory-leaks, mef

I have the following Scenario:

**WCF Windows Service 1**

- Calls WCF Service 2 when there is work to complete
- Updates Database with result

**WCF Windows Service 2**

- Uses Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) to compose a part (Plugin) dynamically in a new App domain.
- The Plugin then creates an instance of Watin (open source .net testing framework) which in turn creates a new IE process, does some WWW navigation does some screen scraping, takes a screen shot
- Everything is returned to the caller.

I am seeing a gradual memory leak in the WCF Windows Service 2 and have to restart it every few days. Having profiled the service in my development environment (in isolation) using perfmon I don't seem to be able to see the memory leak. I have tried to use .Net Memory Profiler but also don't seem to be getting anything conclusive. IDispose is implemented and being called.

I'm starting to think that it is the interaction between the two WCF Windows Services that maybe holding onto object references and preventing IDispose from being called. Has anyone else seen this behaviour? or am I barking up the wrong tree?

and before anyone mentions... I understand what is being done is mad...

Comment: I have had good luck using SciTech's memory profiler (payware) as well as WinDbg + PssCor2, when tracking down managed memory leaks.

Comment: I've been using the .net memory profiler but I'll be honest I'm a bit baffled at the results. The types with positive delta counts are mostly strings or odd security type objects both related to WCF. There are object byte arrays which might be the screenshots being passed back... this led me down the Large Object Heap discussions about the fact that they aren't compacted...but I think that's a red herring. Surely the Garbage collector would try to collect the available memory (from Generation 2 - where the LOH is) before the you run out of memory and get an OutOfMemoryException?

Comment: I suspect it maybe the unmanaged memory causing the problem...just struggling to prove it... even with perfmon and tracking private bytes and # Bytes in all Heaps!...Seem to have differences on the live environment where the problem is and trying to reproduce it on dev....arg

Comment: you can prove native vs. managed memory leak:  use PerfMon and watch the `# Total committed Bytes` and `# Total reserved Bytes` (from .NET CLR Memory) and compare those against `Private Bytes` and `Virtual Bytes` (from Process group).  If only the managed counters increate over time, then you have a managed-only leak.  If both groups of counters increase over time, then it's a native leak.